# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id');

Tags: node.js

**controller.js**

```
question = new Question({
            user_id: req.user.id,
            type,
            head,
            body,
            file,
            answer,
});
```

**Model.js**

```
user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User",
 },
```

**validationtoken.js**

```
if (authHeader && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
    token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("User is not authorized");
      }
      req.user = decoded.user;
      next();
    });

  }
```

After submit new question show as submission fail .i need a solution for this

Comment: what is in `req.user`?

Comment: Are you sure your jwt payload contains a claim named `user`? And if yes, this claim typically is a `string` and not an object ...

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved as follow:

```js
question = new Question({
    user_id: req.user ? req.user.id : null, // Check if req.user is defined
    type,
    head,
    body,
    file,
    answer,
});
```

Add one more if condition inside if (authHeader && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer")):

```js
if (decoded && decoded.user) {
            req.user = decoded.user;
            next();
 }
```